# How to get a DatePicker value in razor?

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here my problem:

**I have an input text and behind a date picker ui:** and **I would like to get the datepicker's value in razor:**

**Index.cshtml**

```
<input id="datePickerCalendar" type= "text"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datePickerCalendar').datepicker({
        altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        dayNamesMin: ["Di", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Je", "Ve", "Sa"],
        monthNames: ["Janvier", "Fevrier", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function () {

            /*('#datePickerCalendar').change(loadCalendar());*/
        }
    });
});
</script>



<table border="1" class="tableCalendar" id="calendar">
<caption> Veuillez sélectionner l'horaire souhaité </caption>
<th id="court"></th>
@foreach(var item in Model)  {
  foreach(var court in item.TennisCourts){
      if (court.Outside == true)
      {
          <td id="court" class="court">Court n°@court.Number (Extérieur)</td>
      }
      else
      {
          <td id="court" class="court">Court n°@court.Number (Intérieur)</td>
      }
  }
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    var chooseDate = $('#datePickerCalendar').value; // here ! This instruction is not correct...


}
```

**I'm Building a dynamic calendar that allow the user to make a reservation for a tennis court...**

**So, my questions are:**

1)How to get the value from the datepicker in razor ? 
2)How can I get the value every time when the user change the date ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to post the form to get the value

Comment: @Anders his question is confusing, but he's asking how to get it in the view (he says razor)

Comment: I think he wants to know how to send the data to the controller, but I can be wrong :D He's mixing Razor and javascript code, very confusing

Comment: Ah yeah, I'm not actually sure. I gave him the instructions on how to retrieve the value in JQuery and subscribe to the change event, but if he wants the data in the controller I'll need to elaborate. Is that what you want Franceso?

Comment: No :D I want to get this value in the view (razor) no in JQuery...

Sorry in fact my questions are confusing... 

First, Is it possible to use the datepicker value in my View (razor) ?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you need it for and paste more of your view and then I'll update my answer :)

Comment: All right I will update my answer

Comment: Ah I see, I'm confused, how would the datepicker's value have been set BEFORE the view is loaded? (that's when that code will execute). Or are you loading the view via AJAX? If so, would it not be easier to put another property in your model to hold the Calendar date?

Comment: My view in not loading via AJAX... I would like to build a calendar like this: http://www.boisdelacambre.be/tableau.php5...

In fact, I have many tennis clubs in my database and so the calendar must rebuild according to the tennisClub of the user who is connected...

So the schedule and the number of tennis court can change...

Comment: So, the QUESTION (stupid question :D) is : is it possible to get a value from the client side to the server side in my view ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to post your value to a action method on the controller, surround the field with a form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Controller", "Action", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

Then change your field into a server side rendered one (So the model binder can capture the new value)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate)
```

The action method needs to take the model as argument and it needs to have the DateTime property named MyDate

**edit:**
If you will be sending values from the server you need to be sure the client datepicker and the serer uses the same date format. This is a bit tricky, but I did this with the globalize jquery plugin, you have to choose if you want to hardcode the ui culture, or if the sever will use the client culture. This is done in web.config

Hardcoded

```
<globalization culture="se-SE" uiCulture="se-SE"  enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
```

Client chooses

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

**edit2**
Sorry for all my edits :D 
A good way for sending server settings like datetime and such is to create a settings razor view and change its mime type to javascript, also be sure to have caching otherwise the client will load it every time

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    Response.Expires = 120;
    Response.CacheControl = "public";
    Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
}

MyAppName = {};
MyAppName.settings = {
    culture: "@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name",
    timeFormat: "@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern.ToLower()",
    dateFormat: "@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToLower().Replace("yyyy", "yy")",
}
```